# serve different content according to header value in Nginx

Tags: web-services, nginx, web, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have some web content behind the follwoing arch, for which I need to serve different content for desktop and mobile clients.

client > AWS Cloudfront > Nginx > ...

cloudfront has the builtin ability to identify the user-agent and they kind of unify it into 4 special headers (for example CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer) which are either true or false.

on Nginx I'm trying to decide which content to serve according to those headers.
for example:

```
 location / {
   if ($http_CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer = true) {
        proxy_pass http://upstream;
        break;
   }
   root /var/www/static/en-US;
   try_files $uri /index.html;
 }
```

so in the above case it should go to the upstream if the CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer value is true, and get the static files from nginx if it's false or not present.

but for some reason I always get the static files from nginx.
I'm sure this header is being forwarded, I've even tried to send it directly from chrome with a header modifier.

what am i missing?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this variable:

$http_cloudfront_is_desktop_viewer

[From manual about embedded variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables):

> $http_name nginx
>
> arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable name is
> the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by
> underscores